# Passing multiple DataFrames Between Scala Spark and PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jvm

I am trying to pass and convert multiple dataframes from scala to pyspark. when i try the it for one dataframe i am able to read the output using .show(), but for multiple dataframes i am not able to split the dataframes and hence cannot convert

I tried to get one dataframe printed by passing from scala spark to pyspark. it works perfectly i wsa even able to convert it to pandas. when i did the same by passing two dataframes i was not able to split the dataframes. i am receiving the data as type 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember' there are two dataframes in this object if i could split them i will be able to convert pyspark dataframe as i did with one scala dataframe

here is the scala code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}

object scala_py{
def getInputDF:(DataFrame,DataFrame)={

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val SourceTableDataframe = spark.sql("select * from <table name>")
val data=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM <table name>")
return (SourceTableDataframe,data)
}}
```

this is pyspark code:

```
from pyspark import StorageLevel, SparkFiles
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PySpark using Scala example") \
    .getOrCreate()
sqlContext = spark._wrapped
sc = spark._sc
scala_out=sc._jvm.com.accenture.asset.scala_py

df1,df2=scala_out.getInputDF()
df=DataFrame(df1,sqlContext)
```

i expect to get my both the scala dataframes(SourceTableDataframe,data) to pyspark dataframes as df1 and df2.

now i am getting the object py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember which i couldnot process.

when i return one dataframe i am getting the same datatype but i am able to convert it to pyspark dataframe, when i try returning two i am not able to get what i need

Answer (score 1):

The object you return is a `scala.Tuple2`, equivalent to:

```
dfs = sc._jvm.scala.Tuple2(spark._jsparkSession.range(1), spark._jsparkSession.range(2))
```

which has no py4j mapping. Therefore you have to process it by hand

```
df1, df2 = DataFrame(dfs._1(), sqlContext), DataFrame(dfs._2(), sqlContext)
```